# PHP in_array and array_key_exists not working for SESSION

Tags: php, session

```
<?php   
session_start();
 if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {

            if(in_array($_GET['code'],$_SESSION["cart_item"])){
                echo "hiiii";
            }else{
                echo "byeee";}
        }else {
            $itemArray = array($_GET['code']=>array('pcode'=>$_GET['code']));
            $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
        }
?>
```

I'm trying to check if there is a similar item store in the $_SESSION[cart_item] using in_array but it only return me false although i make sure that the value is indeed store in $_SESSION.

As i go through some checking, since my $_SESSION has a multidimensional array, i should use array_key_exists and here is my code for this

```
if(array_key_exists($_GET['code'],$_SESSION["cart_item"])){
            echo "hiiii";
        }else{
            echo "byeee";}
```

But still it returns false. Can anyone point out my error?

btw I'm new to this and thanks in advance.

Comment: share your `$_SESSION["cart_item"]` array.

Comment: is in the else { } of my first part of codes

Comment: better change `if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))` to `if(isset($_SESSION["cart_item"]))`

Comment: check this answer: [https://3v4l.org/gmu7k](https://3v4l.org/gmu7k)

Comment: thanks, i think i notice what i did wrong :) have a nice day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))` to `if(isset($_SESSION["cart_item"]))`. Also check for the $_SESSION that is a simple array or not, for matching with `in_array`, you need to have array like i assign.

As you mention _since my $*SESSION has a multidimensional array*, SO make sure your array is a single dimension if you are using `in_array`.

**let the variables likes this:**

```
$_SESSION["cart_item"] = array('1', '2', '3');
$_GET['code'] = '3';

if(isset($_SESSION["cart_item"])) { 
    if(in_array($_GET['code'], $_SESSION["cart_item"])){
        echo "hiiii";
    }else{
        echo "byeee";}
}else {
    $itemArray = array( $_GET['code'] => array('pcode'=> $_GET['code']) );
    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
}
```

**Result:** hiiii

Now its time to use `array_key_exists`.

Lets change array:

```
$_SESSION["cart_item"] = array('1' => array(6, 7, 8), '2' => array(2, 4, 6), '3' => array(1, 5, 9));

if(array_key_exists($_GET['code'], $_SESSION["cart_item"])){
    echo "hiiii from key exists";
}else{
    echo "byeee";
}
```

**Result:** hiiii from key exists

> Note: I think you understand how to use and where to use `in_array`
>   and `array_key_exists`.

Comment: Hi, I think I found the problem. When i tried to save 1 value into the multidimensional array into SESSION, and i get var_dump to show me the output this is what i get array(1) { [333]=> array(1) { ["pcode"]=> string(3) "333" } }. But if i try to save more into the session it becomes this array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["pcode"]=> string(3) "333" } [1]=> array(1) { ["pcode"]=> string(3) "444" } } the key value did not save the value that i assign to it and instead it change to default 0,1,2....